# Using variables from another method - problems understanding the object orientation

Tags: java, object, methods

the following code is incomplete but the main focus of my question is on the method processConfig() anyway. It reads the properties out of a file and I want to handover these properties to the method replaceID(). It worked already when the content of processConfig was in the main()-method. But now I wanted to put this code into it´s own method. What is the best way of handing over the properties (which I saved in Strings like difFilePath). I´m not that familiar with OO-programming and want to understand the concept. Thanks for your help.

```
public class IDUpdater {

....

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //Here I want to call the variables from processConfig() to make them available for replaceID(...)

    replaceID(difFilePath, outputDifPath, encoding);

}

public static void replaceID(String difFilePath, String outputDifPath, String encoding) throws Exception{


    return record;
}

public void processConfig(){

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("File 'config.properties' could not be found.");
    }
    try {
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error("Properties file could not be loaded.");
    }

    String difFilePath = prop.getProperty("dif_file_path");
    String outputDifPath = prop.getProperty("output_dif_path");
    String encoding = prop.getProperty("encoding");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to declare your variables globally. This way they can be accessed in each method. After you've declared them globally you first call your processConfig in your main method, which will set your variables to what they should be.

```
public class IDUpdater {
    private String difFilePath;
    private String outputDifPath;
    private String encoding;

    public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        processConfig();
        replaceID(); 
    }

    public void replaceID() throws Exception{
        // You can use your variables here.
        return record;
    }

    public void processConfig(){
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("File 'config.properties' could not be found.");
        }

        try {
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Properties file could not be loaded.");
        }

        difFilePath = prop.getProperty("dif_file_path");
        outputDifPath = prop.getProperty("output_dif_path");
        encoding = prop.getProperty("encoding");  
    }
}
```

Note that I declared the variables privately. For more information about protecting your variables see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx.

Comment: I would think twice about using "declare your variables globally" phrase.You may want to reword that or you face a possibility of stones being thrown at you.

Comment: But then I have the "static"-problem. And when I make the Strings static I can´t change them afterwards. I´ve already tried that. But thanks for the suggestion. EDIT: When I call replaceID(difFilePath, outputDifPath, encoding); it says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field difFilePath"

Comment: @Kai I'm not sure what you mean with static problem?

Comment: When I try it like in your suggestion Eclipse tells me at the line "replaceID(difFilePath, outputDifPath, encoding);" that it "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field difFilePath". If I turn them static I can´t change them..

Comment: @Kai Does your replaceID method have to be static?

Comment: @lextoc No, it doesn´t have to be. But when I change this, Eclipse tells me in the main method when I call the replaceID that it "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method replaceID() from the type IDUpdater". I´m running circles -.-

Comment: I added the following to my main-method:  IDUpdater idUp = new IDUpdater(); idUp.processConfig();  idUp.replaceID();   now I dont get the static-error - yay

Comment: Try removing static from your main as well (so no static methods). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read an article (or even better yet - a book) on topic of encapsulation and objects. [This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm) or [this](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/encapsulation-in-java/) may be a good starting point for you. There is no point in anyone fixing your code, if you don't understand the concepts behind it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don´t want anybody to fix my code. I just wanted to make clear what my problem is. I will read that article. I already read some other articles about it but i still feel i haven´t understood it completely.